# Pentaho CE 5.0 and R for predictions

Tags: r, pentaho

I use pentaho CE 5.0 and I want to integrate R plugins with pentaho. Does any one know how pentaho and R communicate with each other? Any tutorial or PDF available for integration pentaho with R?

Comment: Everytime I read about this platform I think of pubic hair...

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, do I want to know why? (I don't quite feel like Googling your comment....)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_profanity#Pendejo Kind of an unfortunate choice of name and pronounced very similarly.

Comment: Hi all after searching long time I found this solution http://markahall.blogspot.co.nz/2012/07/r-integration-in-weka.html#!

Answer (score 0):

There is one new plugin for PDI 4.4. I'm not sure if it also works for 5.0.
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/List+of+Available+Pentaho+Data+Integration+Plug-Ins

PRScript Execute R Script

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start to anybody who starts integrating Pentaho with R. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/R+script+executor 
There they provide example ktr files as well.

**Summary of the contents of the link**

- Installation Instructions - Install R, Set R Environment Variables, Configure Spoon with rJava and Verification of Installation.
- Description of options available - Configure tab, R Script tab, Output Fields tab,
- Examples